# React form with multiple buttons - how to choose one to handle onSubmit event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have this HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<p>Output: <span id="output"></span></p>
```

and this JS:

```
function otherAction(e) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'otherAction';
  e.preventDefault();
}

function submit(e) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'submit';
  e.preventDefault();
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <form onSubmit={submit}>
    <input type="text" defaultValue="foo" />
    <button onClick={otherAction}>Other Action</button>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Actually, let's not just say it, let's [put it in a JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/L0urqamz/). What I want to happen is that:

1. Clicking the "Other Action" button triggers the `otherAction` function (it does!)
2. Clicking the "Submit" button triggers the `submit` function (it does!)
3. Putting your cursor in the text box and pressing enter triggers the `submit` function (this does not work currently!)

In #3, what happens instead is that `otherAction` gets triggered. How can I change that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L0urqamz/1/

Comment: or if you swap buttons , then it takes first button https://jsfiddle.net/L0urqamz/2/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you set the first button to type="button" (i.e. provide a type for each button) it should work.

```
<button type="button" onClick={otherAction}>Other Action</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L0urqamz/3/

Answer (score 0):

You should provide types for all buttons, otherwise it won't work:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    // form content
    <button type="button" onClick={someButtonEvent}>DO STH</button>
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```